# Django modelformset_factory does not save to database

Tags: python, django, database, modelform

The issue is that Django modelformset_factory does not save to database when inputs are inserted into the forms. It appears that only else statement is reached after forms are submitted for processing. Clearly the issue is with part in views.py where if 'name' in request.POST: then do sth. Advise how to solve it would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions

model_names = ['Form1', 'Form2']


def get_assumptions(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'name' in request.POST:

        formset = modelformset_factory(
            Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

        if formset.is_valid():

            print('valid form')

            for form in formset:

                if form.is_valid():

                    print('in for loop after valid form1')

                    assumptions = form.save(commit='False')
                    assumptions.Name = 'name'
                    assumptions.save()

    else:

        formset = modelformset_factory(
            Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

        print('reached else')

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset, 'model_names': model_names})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Grey_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Red_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Blue_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Green_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = ['Worst_Case', 'Grey_Case', 'Red_Case', 'Blue_Case', 'Green_Case', 'Best_Case']
        exclude = ['Name']
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
{% for name in model_names %}
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" name="{{name}}" value="save" />
{% endfor %}


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: But you've exclude `name` from form fields. So POST data never contains `name`.

Comment: I did not want this field to be shown to user. Anyway, I tried including it, sitll does not save to database. I think the issue is that that if request.method == 'POST' and 'name' in request.POST: is never satisfied because 'name' is never present in POST. Wonder what is correct way to pass information and distinguish between different forms in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

`name` needs to be in your `request.POST`,
doublecheck your template and add an `input` tag with a `name='name'`

```
<input name='name' />
```